# Bad request (400) error in loadrunner during replay using web protocol

Tags: loadrunner

I see 400 error for the below request in my script. Tried adding all the headers..but doesn't work...any suggestions pls..

```
web_custom_request("submit", 
    "URL=" application URL", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/json", 
    "Snapshot=t5.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "EncType=application/json;charset=utf-8", 
    "Body={\"loan\":{\"borrow\":10000,\"reason\":\"09\"},\"identity\":{\"firstName\":\"Deseriee\",\"lastName\":\"Argue\",LAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add tag "EncType=application/json"

Comment: Also try with change next "Mode=HTTP"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you think of any additions to your posts these can be edited to include the new info by clicking the edit button. Code samples can also be highlighted the clicking Ctrl+K to nicely format them